# Switching Vue components with buttons

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to toggle between two vue components. I have this:

```
<template>
    <button @click="selected = 'A', console.log(selected)">A</button>
    <button @click="selected = 'B', console.log(selected)">B</button>

    <A v-if="selected === 'A'" />
    <B v-if="selected === 'B'" />
</template>

<script setup>
import A from './A.vue';
import B from './B.vue';

let selected = 'A';
</script>
```

which loads component `A` fine on page load, but clicking on the button for `B` does nothing.

Each time I click a button I can see the correct index value in the console, but the components below the buttons don't change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define `selected` to Ref.

```
- let selected = 'A';
+ const selected = ref('A');
```

now Vue can track `selected` change

---

And you can also use like this.

```
<component :is="selected === 'A' ? A : B">
```

Answer (score 0):

在script中定义的变量应该是一个具有响应式的变量，例如

```js
const selected = ref('A');
```

或者

```js
const selected = reactive('A');
```

当然，你需要提前引入`ref`或者`reactive`。

Comment: Hey @DreamSeeker, this answer looks like it could be relevant but you will have to post it in English to share it here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684